# FFMPEG Motion Vector Block Format

Tags: ffmpeg, video, h.264

I'm trying to extract motion vectors from h264 videos using ffmpeg and the `AVSideData` API.  I'm a little confused about the format as there are some subtleties that aren't well documented, and I'm hoping someone knows definitively because I've read some conflicting things in various places about this.

Are the source and destination block locations top-left coords or center coords? When I plot the motion vectors it looks like they are center coords, but if that's the case then how do I compute the size of the block given that the block sizes are even numbers? This would cause me to cut off pixels on the vertical or horizontal axes.

The second questions is that h264 supports half and quarter pixel MV positions, how do I detect and handle this given that the source and destination points are integers only? Do I need to compute it myself using `motion_x`, `motion_y`, and `motion_scale`?  If so then why include the source position at all?

Example images:

Using top-left coords:

[image]

Note the black top-left border

Using center coords:

[image]